# Rails, ActiveJobs and AWS SQS: what happen to my jobs when a worker instance is killed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, rails-activejob, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We are using Rails 5.0.2 and ActiveJobs in AWS Beanstalk with SQS as a backend with the gem [active_elastic_job](https://rubygems.org/gems/active_elastic_job/versions/2.0.1).

We have a job defined like this:

```
class MyJob < ActiveJob::Base
  rescue_from(StandardError) do |exception|
    self.class.set(:wait => 1.minutes).perform_later
  end

  def perform
    MyLongTask.run
  end
end
```

We experienced that when one instance in the worker environment is killed (due auto-scaling or something) the `rescue_from` is not executed and the Job is not sent back to the Queue.

How can we capture the moment the instance is been called to be killed so we can gracefully react and wrapping up before my process is really killed? (if possible)

#### Update

I am trying this

```
class MyJob < ActiveJob::Base
  def perform
    begin
      sleep(100)
    rescue SignalException => e
      # send signal to some log place
      raise e
    end
  end
end
```

But the log is never sent not when I *terminate* the instance neither when I kill the puma process with `$ restart puma`

Comment: What gem do you use as active job backend?

Comment: @mrzasa [active_elastic_job](https://rubygems.org/gems/active_elastic_job/versions/2.0.1)

Comment: This might be a tricky one. In an ideal world the process running your job would receive the termination signal and decide to do something like: if your job doesn't finish in time, it just "goes back" to the queue. This is the sidekiq model, for example.

In your specific case, maybe it would be a (somehow contrived) solution to trap the signal in the web application process itself. But then you would need some mechanism to re-enqueue your job.

I will think about it...

Comment: @RicardoValeriano ActiveJobs has a mechanism to re-enqueue the job `self.perform_later` but I first I have to trap the signal and I still don't see how

Comment: have you tried rescuing from `Exception` instead of `StandardError` because it might be causing a different exception

Answer (score 2):

By catching the `SIGTERM` signal, you can perform any cleanup you'd like before the process is terminated (your environment might send a `SIGKILL` later which cannot be caught).

```
Signal.trap(:SIGTERM) {
  # perform cleanup here
  exit
}
```

Comment: How can I register this in a Rails + ActiveJob environment?

Comment: I am trying the `rescue SignalException` as you can see in the Update of my Question but it is not working

Comment: Register the signal handler at the global level, as part of your initialization. `Signal` is part of `ruby`, not `rails`.